# python distutils include shell scripts in module directory

Tags: python

What is the best way to include a 'helper' shell script in setup.py that is used by a python module? I don't want to include is as a script since it is not run on it's own.

Also, data_files just copies things in the the install path (not the module install path) so that does not really seem like the best route.

I guess the question is: is there a way of including non-python (non-C) scripts/binaries in a python distutils package in a generic way?

Comment: What's a helper script that is used by a python module but not on its own? What precisely are you doing with it?

Comment: Basically it's just a stupid shell script that does something (for example a special grep call maker or sed call maker). The fix is probably just to put the shell text in a python function and never deal with file that are not .py modules. I just thought there might be a workaround of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to package a shell script.

For one of my projects I specifically needed a shell script to pass as an argument over subprocess to another tool that will only except a shell script, not a python script.

So I finally hacked around it by having python write myscript.sh out on the the fly.

It looks like this:

```
bash_script_name = cwd + "/myscript.sh"
bash_script_file_obj = open(bash_script_name, 'w')
bash_script_file_obj.write(text_of_myscript)
bash_script_file_obj.close()
os.chmod(bash_script_name, 0755)

subprocess.call([another_tool, bash_script_name])

os.remove(bash_script_name)
```

It's not very elegant, but it worked.  If you have the choice of writing the script in Python, I would definitely go with that.

Answer (score 3):

Include it in MANIFEST.in, something like this:

`include mycode/myscript.sh`

Here's an example Python package that uses helper scripts:

https://github.com/pminkov/kubeutils

Take a look at this file, it runs shell scripts:
https://github.com/pminkov/kubeutils/blob/master/kubeutils/kutils.py

Answer (score 0):

Another issue might be that such pypi packages containing Bash scripts might not run correctly on e.g. Windows?